# Mvc3 - How to call action from static function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a static function and I need to call specific controller/action with parameters and get the result.
How can this be done?

Comment: Where is the static function? Within the controller you want to call? If not.. you'll be instantiating a new instance..

Comment: Currently is inside same controller, but in general case it can be outside

Comment: @ZombieHunter does it make a difference if it is not static???

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you want to execute an Action w/o an actual Request coming in?

Comment: @Henk Things are little complicated - The Request is comming in but it is handed over to the custom framework which evaluates some "dynamic" expression (evaluated at runtime).
This expression in some cases must call a function which returns an ActionResult. 
So, the actual request exists

Comment: I am really puzzled here... you can easily call action from virtually anywhere - browser, javascript, jquery, view, ... but hardly from custom code... That REALLY SUCKS!

Comment: That's because when the request comes in you have a Controller instance and all the perks that come with it. By going static you seem to lose (give up) that context.

Comment: @Henk OK... suppose I go for the non-static function and I somehow get the name of the controller and action which needs to be executed (I am inside some controller function). How can I then execute that controller/action and return ActionResult?

Comment: Leave the ActionResult object to the actual controller. Create a custom class containing all relevant information and use your static method to return an instance of this class. Then you can build your ActionResult based on the returned object. This way your static method remains independent and can be used by MVC, Web Form, Console Application and so on...

Comment: @Zombie See the previous comment, that is the exactly the approach I need to use

Comment: So you want to call a controller method from another controller method?

Comment: Yes... how to do this? (note that request is Ajax so that redirect approach will not work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of that particular controller and then use the instance's Execute() method to execute the controller.

I do something similar in my Application_Error handler:

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
routeData.Values["action"] = "General";
routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;

IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
try
{
    errorsController.Execute(rc);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Appropriate error handling.
}
```